# In C#, Excel cell's custom date format not working with EPPlus

Tags: excel, c#-4.0, format, epplus

I'm having trouble with Excel's custom format using EPPLUS.  Here's my code:

```
var destFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\temp\test1.xlsx");
var fileName = "test1";
using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(destFile))
{
    pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(fileName); // Create the worksheet in package   
    pck.Workbook.Worksheets[fileName].Cells["A2"].Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    pck.Workbook.Worksheets[fileName].Cells["A2"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "d-mmm-yy";

    pck.Save();
}
```

I'm getting the following:
[image]

The custom format is showed right, but the value in the cell doesn't display the format needed.  Here's what I'm trying to get:
[image]

**Note:**  I need the full date value `DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")` for other files, but the custom format is all I need for this file.

What do I need to change to get this to work?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to apply a number format to a string, which isn't going to do anything.  Have you tried `Cells["A2"].Value = DateTime.Now` so a date value gets written to the cell instead of a string?

Comment: Nope.  But your suggesting did the trick.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @PaullAbbott, here's the correct answer:

```
pck.Workbook.Worksheets[fileName].Cells["A2"].Value = DateTime.Now;
```

This displays the results that I needed.